# Is baking soda effective in absorbing hair grease ("dry wash") if one is unable to wash their hair w/shampoo for whatever reason?

Tags: sebum-oil, baking-soda, shampoo, hair-conditioner, greasy-hair

When I was a youngster & a teenager, I had several ear surgeries, and I was not able to wash my hair for several days (just sponge bath the rest of the body). I always have had long hair, and it's blonde, so when it's not washed... it's very noticeable (especially as a teenager, I was very concerned with my appearances).

I recall that my mother brought out the baking soda from the kitchen, and did a **"dry-wash" of my hair** because it was just so greasy/oily and disgusting and I had to go to Junior High.

My memory escapes me, but **how effective is baking soda in keeping the hair looking clean and fresh (if one is unable to use shampoo or conditioner)? How does it work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, No and no...

A simple google search for the words "baking soda hair" reveals:

> **"Baking soda may cause long-term damage and hair breakage"**

http://www.healthline.com/health/beauty-skin-care/baking-soda-hair#overview1

People use baking soda + vinegar to clean combs and drains...

Don't put it on your hair unless you look like Bruce Willis and going bald might be cool.

Comment: A great answer, short and to the point. I would suggest adding the PMC reference: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4158629/ that is listed in the healthline article. That way if healthline goes inactive you still have a great scientific resource included in your answer.